# Jasper Reports - Docx Generation

Tags: java, jasper-reports, docx

I have some problems with the generation of docx with jasper templates. A lots of elements are not at the right place. (blank page, space, ...).

Is there a solution to avoid this problems ?

P.S: The generation of PDF occurs without this problems.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this question at the [JasperReports Library Forums](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/browse.php?group_id=102&forumid=103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with it as well at the moment and solved my problems by placing the components carefully. You must take care that components don't overlap (or one of them will be discarded).

Its a pain and I still have some problems (Last row table elements sometimes not being printed is one of the worst and I still work on it) but most stuff works.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try [Aspose.Words for JasperReports](http://www.aspose.com/categories/jasperreports-exporters/aspose.words-for-jasperreports/default.aspx) and see if it helps in your scenario? You can also get complete help from [Aspose.Words for JasperReports Documentation](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/jasperreports-exporters/aspose.words-for-jasperreports/introducing-aspose-words-for-jasperreports.html). This component [provides high fidelity to the report designs](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/jasperreports-exporters/aspose.words-for-jasperreports/high-fidelity-to-the-report-design.html).
Please see if it can produce the output with the required quality.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.